# Transitioning from UIImagePickerController to a second UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Still feeling pretty green in Objective-C - building my first "real" project and hit an architectural snag early on..

I'd like to present my views and navigation in a fully 'custom' environment - e.g. something where I hide all of the built-in UI controls (e.g. UINavigationController or UITabBar). One specific example (as in the title): moving from a 'main' view directly to a UIImagePickerController, and then right from the UIImagePickerController to a new third view.

Here are the three primary view controllers I'm working with:

- **MainViewController** (custom subclass of UIViewController, contains my main Nav and is in general my primary or 'parent' controller)
- **ImageEditViewController** (custom subclass of UIViewController wherein I overlay some controls on top of a stored image)
- **UIImagePickerController** (built-in Apple class)

There are a couple of approaches I can image for this (but I can't figure out how to do either one):

1. **Use a UINavigationController or UITabBar implementation**, but somehow hide the system UI controls and implement my own. I am blocked on this approach because - simply - *I don't know how to hide the system UI controls*.
2. **Call controller-to-controller or view-to-view transitions manually** at specific points in the code. I sort of prefer this method but I can't figure out the best 'approach' to instantiating and managing and transitioning between my controllers. Example of things I don't know: how do I call a second view controller from my main view controller? How do I call a third view controller directly from the second? (Or at least transition to the third directly!)

I assume there is an easy solution here; just something I haven't learned yet about managing views and view controllers outside of Apple's helper classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What system UI controls are you talking about? The navigation bar?

You can just do `myNavigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES`; for a `UINavigationCOntroller`.

Documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

As for the kind of navigation you should have, that really depends on your use case. Are you trying to achieve a hierarchy or workflow? Then perhaps a navigation controller is what you want. Is each view controller a separate piece that does not necessarily follow a workflow? Then a tab bar controller could work.

For tab bar you should be able to do something like:

```
myTabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
[[myTabBarController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)]; // or whatever your screen dimensions are
```

Comment: yes - sorry - I was talking about like UINavigationController and UITabBar - i'll update the question as such, but you may have just solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

1.
For hiding navigation bar, it's quite easy:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

For Hiding TabBar Use this:

```
- (void) hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {


[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
{
if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
{
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
} 
else 
{
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
}

}

[UIView commitAnimations];





}

- (void) showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
{

if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
{
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];

} 
else 
{
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 431)];
}


}

[UIView commitAnimations]; 
 }
```

2.

If you want to easily be able to navigate backwards you should use a navigation controller, it will allow you to pop the view controller when you are done with it. Or you can do something like this (outside of navigation controller):

```
CustomViewController *controller = [[CustomViewController alloc] init];

[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```